# Ruby Has Many Association Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

Whenever I tried to run this rake command:

```
@user = User.find("1")
@contest = Contest.find("1")
@user.votes.create(:user => self, :contest => @contest)
```

I get this error:

```
User(#70104671283680) expected, got Object(#70104612331400)
```

This is my User.rb

```
has_many :votes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :votes
attr_accessible :votes_attributes
```

This is my Contest.rb

```
has_many :votes
```

And these are my migrations:

```
change_table :users do |t|
  t.references :votes
end

change_table :contests do |t|
  t.references :votes
  t.references :contest_items
end

change_table :votes do |t|
  t.belongs_to :users
  t.belongs_to :contests
end
```

Am I setting the votes incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `self` with a User, for example `@user`.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing self with @user, will do the job.

Ideally you should do this.

```
@user.votes.create(:contest => @contest)
```

Rails Will take care of the assignment internally if you associations are properly setup.

In your case It will.

I have taken this snippets from rails guides.

```
@order = @customer.orders.create(:order_date => Time.now)
```

This is the URL

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html